# What part of Apple's review process might lead to them reject apps with not-complete features?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

Will Apple decline an app from the App Store if a test feature is in place? I've looked over the generic [App review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html) but don't know how or where the line is drawn.

For an example specific to my case, we want to add a button that will redirect a user to a coming soon page on our website.  We ultimately want to see how many users are clicking on the button to gauge how much interest there is in this product/feature.

Comment: I was going to close this since as asked, it's primarily opinion-based. Anyone could give their opinion and there is no research done to qualify what would make a good answer. However, [we only recently opened up itunes-connect questions](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1664/update-to-faq-about-itunes-connect-being-on-topic), so the site needs a good example of How to ask this sort of question.

Comment: So forgive us for editing this drastically. Please ask about the edit process on the [meta] side of the site if you have heartburn about this. I'd rather not close it as being [not constructive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv).

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  This has happened to me.  Apple sends your submission through a light testing regime by a human.  If they pick up an egregious bug or substantially incomplete feature, they may reject your submission.

You could change the verbiage on the button to make it clear the feature is not yet implemented, which would probably pass.

One suggestion is to have a live blog and link to discussions, using a redirect from your web server to track which button was pressed in the app.  This way, reviewers arrive at a logical page while you could track which version of the app was used. Why risk rejection for submitting something with an incomplete feature when you can have a simple "coming soon" link before you submit your app for review?

Comment: As far as I know any mention to beta in version number or incomplete/not implemented functionality in application should automatically lead to application rejection. Which is, I think, perfectly normal.